# Definition for a C# Generic Class with a 'matching' Generic Interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to declare a generic class (Factory) for a DbContext (EF6) in an ASP.NET Core (MVC6) application. The problem is I need an interface type for the Dependency Injection.

I've tried multiple approaches, and google (uncharacteristically) seems to be no help. This either means my searches are using the wrong words, or what I'm trying to do is totally wrong.

So the question is:

If I have two DbContexts in a project, and I want to create a generic factory which can create a context to either of these using a single method (called CreateContext()), with a generic interface so I can use dependency injection, what is the correct class definition please?

Example Interface:

```
public interface IDbContext<C> where C: DbContext
{
    C CreateContext(); //<-- generic bit required here for this method
}
```

Example Factory:

```
public class DbContextFactory<C> : IDbContext<C>, where C: DbContext //<--unable to get this correct
{
    private C _context = null;
    private string _connectionstring;

    public DbContextFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }    

    public C CreateContext()
    {
       try
       {
          var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<C>();
          optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
          //_context = new C(optionsBuilder.Options); //<-- issue here also
          _context = default(C); //<-- how to pass options??
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         // log some error here
       }
       return _context;
    }
}
```

Any help on this subject would be very much appreciated.
:)

Comment: Remove the comma in the class declaration: `public class DbContextFactory<C> : IDbContext<C> where C: DbContext`

Comment: As stupid as it might seem, that actually was the answer (with additional small alterations), so thank you for the answer. Would you like the points, as I'm happy to award if you "answer" this?

Comment: Well this is really a "typo" question now, so I already voted to close it as such.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly stated, the correct definition is:

Interface remains the same...

```
public class DbContextFactory<C> : IDbContext<C> where C: DbContext
{
  ...
}

public C CreateContext() ...
```

This works as expected.